# MVC : Upload List of files and save in Folder(name-GUID) for individual

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I want to upload multiple files from the various user and saves them all at server with individual folder for each user,which contains list of uploaded files by him.

Requirement:If user uploads 5 files,all five files will be stored within a single folder with GUID FolderName.

My below code creates a new folder for each files upload by a user.
Ex:If user uploads 5 files,all five files will be stored within five different folder with GUID FolderName.

My Controller Upload method is as shown below:

```
 ##Controller Code##

    public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
    {            var testfolder = this.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/");
             string newGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
             string pathToCreate = Path.Combine(testfolder, newGuid);
             if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathToCreate))
             {
                 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.Combine(testfolder, newGuid));
             }
             var fileName = pathToCreate + "//" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
             file.SaveAs(fileName);                              
             return "OK"; 
     }
```

##View Code##

```
  @{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
   <link href="@Href("~/Content/uploadify.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="@Href("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <div class="row">
 <div style="width: 50%;">

        <input type="file" id="multipleFiles" style="width: 50%;" /><div style="width:     77%;
            float: right" id="progressbar">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fileQueue"></div>
   </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"                          type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="@Href("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="@Href("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="@Href("~/Scripts/jquery.uploadify.js")" type="text/javascript">   </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

         $(function () {
     $("#multipleFiles").uploadify({
        'swf': 'Scripts/uploadify.swf',
        'cancelImg': '/Images/trash.jpg',
        'buttonText': 'Add Documents',
        'uploader': 'Upload/Upload',
        'folder': '/uploads',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
        'fileExt': '', //'*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'multi': true,
        'removeCompleted': false,
        'auto': false,
        'height': '30px',
        'queueID': 'fileQueue'
           });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Nowhere in that code is a user mentioned. (How) do your users log in? (How) do you store user properties? You can for example save the GUID in the session for each user.

Comment: @CodeCaster.. Here i get the user from the cookies...Also can't it done without using session's because i wanted to store list of files in a particular folder with Guid for each user.                     Any help would be appreciated..:)

Comment: _"Guid for each user"_ - that's why I suggested to store the GUID in the session, as the session is per user...

Comment: @CodeCaster .... Sorry,As default time of a session is 20 minutes.If the same user uploads other set of files ,those files would be saved under same folder. Here my requirement is to save each set of files within a different folder and that folder should be unique for each upload submit action(containing multiple files)

Comment: Your problem is not about folders or GUIDs, it's about storing properties on a per-user basis. You must generate the GUID once and depending on how you manage your users, store it with the user's profile.

Comment: @CodeCaster ... i had tried with below code lines..but no changes my code behaves same.....        string newGuid= string.Empty;//= Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                 if (newGuid.ToString() == null)
                 {
                     Session["Folder"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                      newGuid = Session["Folder"].ToString();
                 }                                                          Any help would be great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, given that you can't use Sessions, I propose the following:

Generate the GUID in the view and include the url as part of the url you are posting to:

Warning: this code comes with no guarantee, I have not tested it so may need some adjustment. Please consider the idea behind it to be more important.  :)

View Code:

```
 $(function () {

     var guid= '@(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())'; //generated on render time

     $("#multipleFiles").uploadify({
        'swf': 'Scripts/uploadify.swf',
        'cancelImg': '/Images/trash.jpg',
        'buttonText': 'Add Documents',
        'uploader': 'Upload/Upload?guid='+guid, //modified to include guid
        'folder': '/uploads',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
        'fileExt': '', //'*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'multi': true,
        'removeCompleted': false,
        'auto': false,
        'height': '30px',
        'queueID': 'fileQueue'
     });
});
```

Controller Code:

```
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData, Guid guid)  {
    //now you can use the guid to save the files
}
```

Comment: As per your suggestion now GUID is a constant for an user.If the same user uploads other set of files ,those files would be saved under same folder. Here my requirement is to save each set of files within a different folder and that folder should be unique for each upload submit action(containing multiple files)

Comment: ok, my bad, didn't understand you correctly. I'm gonna edit and try again.

Comment: there, second attempt.

Comment: Wow..its mind blowing.. your solution worked on the fly without any issues....thank you so much..:) :)

Comment: When the same user refreshes the page between uploading two files, the GUIDs will still differ.